# How to confirm if Notification already exists?

Tags: android

I don't see any methods in the NotificationManager to check if a given notification already is active, should I be keeping my own logic for this or am I missing something??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should be writing your app such that you do not care whether or not an existing `Notification` is on the screen.

That being said, between `deleteIntent` and `contentIntent`, you can track whether or not the `Notification` is on-screen yourself, if you so desire.

Comment: there can be a case where you have to update the notification if it exists. Wouldnt that be a valid use case for this kind of behavior?

Comment: @JayshilDave: IMHO, no. The question should not be "does the notification exist?", but rather "do the underlying conditions, based upon this state change, call for a notification?". Since raising a new notification and updating an existing notification use the same code (`notify()`, etc.), so long as you are raising the notification when the state requires it, you handle both the new and update scenarios. Use `deleteIntent` to determine if the user got rid of the notification, if that needs to be part of your state.